# How to assign numbers to characters in dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, pytorch, one-hot-encoding

I have a sequence generation and in the final result, I have a tensor that contains my sequence, I have that tensor which is one_hot_encoded and an alphabet and I try to inverse that one_hot_encoded to characters, I try dictionary and `argmax` function but I could not find any solution that can do it all tensor at once and most of the answers do just one character

```
int_to_char = dict((i, c) for i, c in enumerate(alphabet))
inverted = int_to_char[argmax(onehot_encoded[0])]
print(inverted)
```

this is how I use `argmax` and its answer

```
a.argmax(-1)


tensor([10,  4, 17,  ..., 19, 16, 20])
```

these are alphabet and expected result

```
alphabet = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G','H', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'Y', '*', 'X']

data = "MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLTTRTQLPPAYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQDLFLPFFSNVTWFHAIHVSGTNGTKRFDNPVLPFNDGVYFASTEKSNIIRGWIFGTTLDSKTQSLLIVNNATNVVIKVCEFQFCNDPFLGVYYHKNNKSLMESEFRVYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDLEGKQGNFKNXREFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHTPINLVRDLPQGFSALEPLVDLPIGINITRFQTLLALHRSYLTPGDSSSGWTAGAAAYYVGYLQPRTFLLKYNENGTITDAVDCALDPLSETKCTLKSFTVEKGIYQTSNFRVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCVADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYNYKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYLYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSTPCNGVKGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNFNFNGLTGTGVLTESNKKFLPFQQFGRDIADTTDAVRDPQTLEILDITPCSFGGVSVITPGTNTSNQVAVLYQGVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGSNVFQTRAGCLIGAEHVNNSYECDIPIGAGICASYQTQTNSPRRARSVASQSIIAYTMSLGAENSVAYSNNSIAIPTNFTISVTTEILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYICGDSTECSNLLLQYGSFCTQLNRALTVIAVEQDKNTQEVFAQVKQIYKTPPIKDFGGFNFSQILPDPSKPSKRSFIEDLLFNKVTLADAGFIKQYGDCLGDIAARDLICAQKFNGLTVLPPLLTDEMIAQYTSALLAGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPFAMQMAYRFNGIGVTQNVLYENQKLIANQFNSAIGKIQDSLSSTASALGKLQDVVNQNAQALNTLVKQLSSNFGAISSVLNDILSRLDKVEAEVQIDRLITGRLQSLQTYVTQQLIRAAEIRASANLAATKMSECVLGQSKRVDFCGKGYHLMSFPQSAPHGVVFLHVTYVPAQEKNFTTAPAICHDGKAHFPREGVFVSNGTHWFVTQRNFYEPQIITTDNTFVSGNCDVVIGIVNNTVYDPLQPELDSFKEELDKYFKNHTSPDVDLGDISGINASVVNIQKEIDRLNEVAKNLNESLIDLQELGKYEQYIKWPWYIWLGFIAGLIAIVMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSEPVLKGVKLHYT*"
```

I want to turn this tensor into characters based on an alphabet, How can I do that?

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: @CutePoison I edit the question and post both alphabets and expected result

Comment: Why is it that it is the expected result? What is the mapping from the tensor to the letter? Is it "A"=1, "B"=2 or.. ?

Comment: @CutePoison this expected result is just a sample to see how the answer should be, yes A = 1, C = 2, based on alphabet and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a sequence of *int*s, here is a sample:

```
encoded = torch.tensor([10,  4, 17, 19, 16, 20])
```

You could apply a *list* comprehension on your sequence, accessing `alphabet` to extract the letter corresponding to each index:

```
>>> ''.join(alphabet[e] for e in encoded)
MFVYT*
```

---

Given a *str* sequence of letters:

```
data = 'MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLTTRTQLPPAYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQDLFLPFFSNVTWFHAIHVSGTNGTKRFDNPVLPFNDGVYFASTEKSNIIRGWIFGTTLDSKTQSLLIVNNATNVVIKVCEFQFCNDPFLGVYYHKNNKSLMESEFRVYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDLEGKQGNFKNXREFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHTPINLVRDLPQGFSALEPLVDLPIGINITRFQTLLALHRSYLTPGDSSSGWTAGAAAYYVGYLQPRTFLLKYNENGTITDAVDCALDPLSETKCTLKSFTVEKGIYQTSNFRVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCVADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYNYKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYLYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSTPCNGVKGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNFNFNGLTGTGVLTESNKKFLPFQQFGRDIADTTDAVRDPQTLEILDITPCSFGGVSVITPGTNTSNQVAVLYQGVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGSNVFQTRAGCLIGAEHVNNSYECDIPIGAGICASYQTQTNSPRRARSVASQSIIAYTMSLGAENSVAYSNNSIAIPTNFTISVTTEILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYICGDSTECSNLLLQYGSFCTQLNRALTVIAVEQDKNTQEVFAQVKQIYKTPPIKDFGGFNFSQILPDPSKPSKRSFIEDLLFNKVTLADAGFIKQYGDCLGDIAARDLICAQKFNGLTVLPPLLTDEMIAQYTSALLAGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPFAMQMAYRFNGIGVTQNVLYENQKLIANQFNSAIGKIQDSLSSTASALGKLQDVVNQNAQALNTLVKQLSSNFGAISSVLNDILSRLDKVEAEVQIDRLITGRLQSLQTYVTQQLIRAAEIRASANLAATKMSECVLGQSKRVDFCGKGYHLMSFPQSAPHGVVFLHVTYVPAQEKNFTTAPAICHDGKAHFPREGVFVSNGTHWFVTQRNFYEPQIITTDNTFVSGNCDVVIGIVNNTVYDPLQPELDSFKEELDKYFKNHTSPDVDLGDISGINASVVNIQKEIDRLNEVAKNLNESLIDLQELGKYEQYIKWPWYIWLGFIAGLIAIVMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSEPVLKGVKLHYT'
```

You could apply a *list* comprehension on your sequence, this time retrieving the index in alphabet for each letter:

```
>>> encoding = [alphabet.index(x) for x in data]
```

Alternatively you can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> encoding = map(lambda x: alphabet.index(x), data)
```

Comment: this is work if we have the data, the point is I want to use this for sequence generating data and in that case, I just have the tensor of `tensor([10,  4, 17,  ..., 19, 16, 20])` and I should find the answer just based on this tensor

Comment: So you want to predict `data` from that tensor? Can you please clarify what is your input and the desired output of the operation?

Comment: yes, I want to predict data from this tensor, the desire output should be a sequence that like the sequence that I post @Ivan

Comment: I have edited my answer, see above.